# FoldList type evaluation for multivariable function

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, code-request, code, multivalued

In the example code which follows I define a two variable conditional function h[_i, _v], one variable denotes the integer index i, and the other is an N-dimensional vector v (I denote dimension 'N' by 'Num'). I am interested in how to do a folding list type evaluation (or any other efficient method) of this two variable function h[_i,_v], where we carry over the evaluated vector value v to the next index i.e. For Num = 3 I am looking for $$h[3,h[2,h[1,v]]].$$ The code which defines this function h is as follows:

```
Num = 3; p;

M0 = {{Sqrt[1 - p], 0}, {0, Sqrt[1 - p]}}; M1 = {{Sqrt[p], 
   0}, {0, -Sqrt[p]}}; Id = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};

A1 = Table[Id, {i, Num - 1}]; PrependTo[A1, M0]; Pe = Permutations[A1];
MM0 = Table[KroneckerProduct @@ Pe[[i]], {i, Length[A1]}];

A2 = Table[Id, {i, Num - 1}]; PrependTo[A2, M1];
Pe = Permutations[A2];
MM1 = Table[KroneckerProduct @@ Pe[[i]], {i, Length[A2]}];

e1 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], Num]
e2 = RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], Num]

f[i_, v_] := MM1[[i]] . v/Norm[MM1[[i]] . v]
g[i_, v_] := MM0[[i]] . v/Norm[MM0[[i]] . v]
h[i_, v_] := If[e1[[i]] < e2[[i]], f[i, v], g[i, v]]
```

The available documentation seems to specifically address the single variable FoldList case.
Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Fold` and switch `i` and `v` in your definition of `h` ...

```
h[v_, i_] := ...

Fold[h, v, Range[3]]

(* h[h[h[v, 1], 2], 3] *)
```

... or switch the order directly in `Fold`.

```
h[i_, v_] := ...

Fold[h[#2, #1] &, v, Range[3]]

(* h[3, h[2, h[1, v]]] *)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the response. Just one query, how would you adapt the code to repeat this folding process for a given number of rounds. Hence for two rounds I am interested in $$[3,h[2,h[1,h[3,h[2,h[1,v]]]]]].$$ You can advise if I should post as separate question.

Comment: Use ``Nest``: ``Nest[Fold[h[#2, #1] &, #, Range[3]] &, v, 2]``.

Comment: This might be a trivial question (new to Mathematica), but how exactly are you using #2 and #1 to switch arguments? Is this something that you can only do this way within the Fold function? Or is this a general trick for argument switch?

Comment: The syntax above uses [_pure functions_](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/WorkWithPureFunctions.html), and the hash symbols represent [``Slot``](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html). It is a much more general and broader concept, and it is not something special for ``Fold``.